# How to export list of prop values as txt to a certain folder? And how to import them back?

Tags: python, scripting

How to export list of prop values as .txt to *Local Disk (C:) > Blender game > New Folder*?
And how to import them back?

Now im creating save and load game: global position, stats, items etc...
and im planning to save it as list.

Tho im not sure how to do it.

Let's say I have informantion set as var `myprop` and `myprop2`.

Btw... how to get globalPosition?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general file I/O in Python, not Blender.

Comment: Now it works? i mean its not off topic?

Comment: It still is, but a brief answer that directs you to the relevant Python docs should be fine whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a very simple example, of how you could write out something to a text file:

```
import os

# Ensure all folders of the path exist
path = "C:/Blender game/YourFolder/"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

# Write data out (2 integers)
with open(path + "file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("%i %i" % (myprop, myprop2))

# Read back in
with open("C:/Blender game/YourFolder/file.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    a, b = map(lambda x: int(x), data.split(" "))
    print("Imported integers:", a, b)
```

Note that `C:` is usually the system partition and in order to write to it, you must have elevated rights (run Blender as administrator).

Other possible ways to dump and re-import data is to use the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) (binary), [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) (python object serialization) or maybe [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) if you want something human readable. You can come up with your very own text-based format too of course, like shown in my example above, but it can be come tricky to parse very soon. I discourage the use of XML, as it's rather complicated to use in Python without additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example with a string and integer variable

```
prop1 = "abc"
prop2 = 123

# write to file
f = open("props.txt", "w")
print("%s\n%d" % (prop1,prop2), file=f)
f.close()

# read back
prop1 = ""
prop2 = 0

f = open("props.txt", "r")
prop1 = f.readline()
prop2 = int(f.readline())
f.close()

# test 
print(prop1)
print(prop2)
```